# How to create and then write on a xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to python and odoo. I came across a scenario that i want to create a excel file first from my dynamic records and then want to save it to `ir.attachment` table. So that i can link that as an attachment in email.

Here is what i tried, but its not writing into the file

```
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
    worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)
    worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
    worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)
    workbook.close()
```

**Update**

I am able to create the xlsx file, actullay it was my path issue. Now i just want to know that how to add that file in `ir.attachment`

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not writing into the file"? Is the file being created but not populated? Also, you seem to be using imports that are not provided here. Please provide the full code for your [mcve]

Comment: sorry, updating my question in a bit

Comment: @Ancient, I've run your code without any problems, as is, and I can see the xlsx file as intended. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: @Eugene see mu update

Comment: @Ancient, You may try to convert .xlsx file into binary and then pass it, create `ir.attachment` record. For example: `{'datas': binary_file_output}` and you need to pass other parameters which are required to create `ir.attachment`

Comment: why can't you try with pandas library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create xlsx file dynamically and attach via email.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import base64
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)
fp = StringIO()
workbook.save(fp)
fp.seek(0)
datas = base64.encodestring(fp.read())
file_name = "name_%s" %(time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.xlsx'))
attachment=[]
attachment_data = {
    'name':file_name,
    'datas_fname':file_name,
    'datas':datas,
    'res_model':"modelname",
    }
attachment.append(self.env['ir.attachment'].create(attachment_data).id)

mail_obj=self.env['mail.mail']
mail_template=self.env.ref('mail_template_id')        
msg_ids=mail_template.send_mail(id of object)
msgs=mail_obj.browse(msg_ids)
msgs.write({'attachment_ids': [(6, 0, attachment)]})
```

In above code we have create one worksheet record and after that create attachment record.

> You need to give **name,datas_fname,datas,res_model** to create
>   attachment. you can also give res_id to create attachment, after that
>   system will automatic visible attachment inside that model and record.

**After create attachment you can use dynamically in the email.**

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own excel report with the help of these modules: [`report_xls`](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_xls/) [`report_xlsx`](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_xlsx/)

There are modules that already use the `report_xls` module, but you can look for them in the Odoo Apps or in the OCA repository

Once you have the report you can use them as the rest of the PDF reports

Comment: is there any example in your sight where `report_xls` is used

Comment: OCA module `account_balance_reporting_xls` uses `report_xls`.

Comment: If you check the [8.0 version](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/report_xls/) you can read some explanations as well